# API with Google Script Apps

Tags: javascript, json, api, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm having trouble using Google Apps to interact with a management software called Kissflow.

```js
function fun2() {

var id = "yyy";
var apisecretkey = "xxx";
var url ='https://'+id+'.kissflow.com/api/1/verify';
var options = {
  method: 'post',
  headers : {"Authorization" : " Basic " + Utilities.base64Encode(id + ":" + apisecretkey)},
  payload: {
    "grant_type": "client_credentials",
    "scope": "basic+user"
  },
  muteHttpExceptions: true
};
var response = JSON.parse(UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options).getContentText());
}
```

I would like to run this simple example of the API documentation, the goal is for me to be able to send data to the software through my interactions in a spreadsheet, for example. If you can help me in this I will be very grateful, I am new with API's :)

The following error appears: SyntaxError: unexpected token <in JSON at position 0 (line 30, file "Code") I don't know if I'm using this function correctly.

[Kissflow API Documentation](https://help.kissflow.com/en/articles/504567-rest-api-points)

Answer (score 0):

```
JSON.parse(UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options).getContentText())
```

Remove JSON.parse() from above line and output the response on your console using Logger.log() or to your browser log using console.log() and see the result. If there are errors it'll show more user friendly error message.

Answer (score 0):

While I'm not familiar with the API, I suspect the issue is related to this line:

```
var response = JSON.parse(UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options).getContentText());
```

You're fetching the response (which is probably JSON), then getting the content **text** of that response, then **trying to parse that text as if it were JSON**.

So (**solution 1**) if you set your `response` variable equal to

```
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options).getContentText();
```

and try printing that variable to the console, you may find you have something you can work with.

Alternatively (**solution 2**), you might try:

```
var response = JSON.parse(UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options));
```

if you'd rather have a JavaScript object to work with instead of a string (and assuming the `.fetch` method you're calling does indeed provide a JSON-formatted response.)

Comment: Well, now I get a diferent error and the `muteHttpExceptions: true` show the Http page. I want do something like `curl -H "api_key:<your_api_key>" -X GET https://<your_account_id>.appspot.com/api/1/verify` or post somethin with the API like `curl -H "api_key:<your_api_key>" -X POST --data-urlencode "PlaceVisited=Singapore" --data-urlencode "Amount=10000" https://<your_account_id>.appspot.com/api/1/Travel Claim/create  `  that returns something like `{
    PlaceVisited: "Singapore"
    Amount: 10000
    Id: "Sh2a6b8c51_84e7_11e3_bdd0_ddc2c98b0428"
    Subject: "Request for Singapore"
}`.

Comment: as i'm new to API I feel confused when trying to pass this to javascript, understand? Thanks for your help.